# PATCH for many-to-many field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models, modelA and modelB with a many-to-many relationship. I want a PATCH request on /test/{id} which points to TestView to update both modelA and modelB. Not able to find a suitable way to do it.

**models.py**

```
class modelA(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class modelB(models.Model):
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field4 = models.ManyToManyField(modelA)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class modelAserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField()
    field2 = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = modelA
        fields = ('field1', 'field2',)


class modelBserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field3 = serializers.CharField()
    field4 = modelAserializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # **trying to update the models here**
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = modelB
        fields =  ('field3', 'field4',)
```

**views.py**

```
class TestView(Modelviewset):
    serializer_class = modelBserializer
    queryset = modelB.objects.all()
```

This is the payload with which I am trying to PATCH.

```
{
    "field3": "check1",
    "field4": [
    {
        "field1": "check1",
        "field2": "check1"
    },
    {
        "field1": "check2",
        "field2": "check2"
    }
}
```

Comment: could you share the error/problem you encountered?

Comment: I am not able to find a suitable way to do it. If I try patching directly, I get 
                                                                                              
                'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'field1'.

Answer (score 3):

YOU MUST ADD ID FIELD IN SERIALIZER MAN!

```
class modelAserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField()
    field2 = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = modelA
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'id')
```

Also in modelBserializer:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.field3 = validated_data.get('field3', instance.field3)
        if validated_data.get('field4'):
            filed4 = validated_data.pop('field4')
            for item in filed4:
                other_inst = modelA.object.get(id=item.get('id'))
                other_inst.field1 = item.get('field1')
                other_inst.field2 = item.get('field2')
                other_inst.save()
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

After that you must use

```
{
    "field3": "check1",
    "field4": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "field1": "check1",
        "field2": "check1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "field1": "check2",
        "field2": "check2"
    }]
}
```

Comment: validated_data has no key field4! Patching throws and exception  -'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'field1'

Comment: There is no need to define id field, primary_key for that purpose is auto-generated

Comment: Problem remains the same,  validated_data has no key for field4!

Comment: what if `field4 = modelAserializer(many=True, read_only=False)`